# I get and error when I try to do pip install

Tags: python, pip

Every single time I try to install something using the pip install command, a whole bunch of errors just hops in, I've had this problem for a while, I've tried searching up solutions and they didnt work. now im here asking for some help :)

This is the red text that shows up when I do the command

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\kevin løfgren\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\kevin løfgren\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\KEVINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpi743067b'
         cwd: C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wli5xph4\pyinstaller_493a92d116a644ecb3d769ba9d19aa63
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tr16djzk\pyinstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tr16djzk\pyinstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tr16djzk\pyinstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tr16djzk\pyinstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tr16djzk\pyinstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tr16djzk\pyinstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tr16djzk\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tr16djzk\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 0: invalid start byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    warning: no files found matching 'pyinstaller-gui.py'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tr16djzk\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Kevin Løfgren\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tr16djzk\pyinstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\kevin løfgren\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\kevin løfgren\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\KEVINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpi743067b' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: may you add more details about the OS (looks like Windows) and the python version? from the error code looks like it's a 32bit version of python. does it match the OS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `wheel` package is not detected.

Try installing it with:

`pip install wheel`

Answer (score 1):

I think that it could be a permission problem. Execute the Windows shell as admin and try again.